# Open New Window, Pause 5 Secs, Redirect, Pause 5 Secs, Redirect, Repeat

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a button open a pop-up window that on page load redirects to mysite.com
it then waits on mysite.com for a specified amount of time then redirects, and repeats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the popup contain an `<iframe>`, and control the target in an JavaScript timer within the popup page, or and I have not tested this, get the handle of the popup and try to change the window.location of that window.

### `<iframe>` method

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var urls = new Array("p1.html","p2.html");
        var currentUrl = 0;
        var interval = setInterval("updateFrame()", 1000);
        function updateFrame() {
            currentUrl = currentUrl == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            document.getElementById("container").src = urls[currentUrl];
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="container" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here you need to replace `"p1.html","p2.html"` with your own urls. You'll also need to change `currentUrl = currentUrl == 0 ? 1 : 0;` if you have more than two in your array. The `1000` refers to milliseconds - change to 5000 for 5 seconds.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without an iframe?
I know there is but how is the question -.-

Comment: Try adjusting the `window.location` of the popup from the parent, possibly. Method would be the same as for the iframe.

Comment: Alright, just a min and I'll post a working demo - does jsfiddle not work with popups? Getting expected 404s from it when I try.

Comment: Alright - hopefully you can get the idea for this now? Make two pages p1.html and p2.html and just fill them with different text to make testing easier. If you'd prefer to this all in one page, you can extract most of the code and just replace the `document.getElementById("container").src` with a handle to the popup.

Comment: To make it clear - the page I've given above should BE the popup. You're not going to embed that in a page.

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much for your help :D
i really appreciate it.